# How to close a Form with a button and open another Form

Tags: c#

So what happened is that I am creating my first ever UI program and when I go into the settings app then I click exit. What I want to happen is to come back to another form but it closes the application altogether.

I have already tried `this.Close();` but that is the thing that is causing the problem is what I feel.

```cs
   Login log = new Login();
   this.Close();
   log.Show();
```

I wanted it to show another form which is called 'Login' but it just closed the entire application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try

```
Me.Close();
```

we don't use "this" in windows form applications

Comment: Does that work for c#?

Comment: Because in my c# project, it says that it is not in the context

Comment: No it does not. This will not compile and it's blatantly wrong.

Comment: You are confusing VB.NET with C#.

Comment: @Joelius It does say that as I quote:

Comment: @EinstienLover Joelius was commenting to Youssef not to you :)

Comment: ``` The name 'Me' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yea actually you are correct my bad, just the look brought up my memory to that language.. i am sorry about that